# Trying to render a template, getting an error html/template: "templates/index.html" is undefined

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a simple main.go script that loads a template from a folder.  The template looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>T2 template</title>
</head>
<body>
 hello
</body>
</html>
```

The main.go script looks is:

```
package main

import (

  "fmt"
  "html/template"
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "os"

  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var (
  templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html"))
)

func main() {

  port := os.Getenv("PORT")

  fmt.Printf("port is: %v\n", port)

  r := mux.NewRouter()

  r.HandleFunc("/hello", HomeHandler)

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, r))
}

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  tmpl := "templates/index.html"

  err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl, "")
  if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here.

The error I see in the browser is:

> "templates/index.html" is undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ParseFiles](https://godoc.org/html/template#ParseFiles) doc says:

> The returned template's name will have the (base) name and (parsed) contents of the first file.

To execute the template, use the [base name](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Base) of "templates/index.html":

```
tmpl := "index.html"
err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl, "")
```

Comment: Ok, so if I will have many folders and numerious index.html files I can't use parse files then right?

Comment: That's correct.  The documentation says: *When parsing multiple files with the same name in different directories, the last one mentioned will be the one that results. For instance, ParseFiles("a/foo", "b/foo") stores "b/foo" as the template named "foo", while "a/foo" is unavailable.*   ParseFiles is a helper method. Can can copy the logic and name the templates however you want.